# How we can create preloader for vue js component with slots?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have vue.js component that has slots with data. My problem is showing data before creating component completely. Before component initialized, We have text which after creating component, it will be insert to component slot. I want to don't show these before initializing component. Is there any component config to this?

Answer (score 1):

`v-cloak` you can always use v-cloak for this, 
For example

```
<h1 v-cloak>my text<h1>
```